# Solving differential equations in MAPLE (ballistic curve problem)

Tags: computational-physics, maple

***TASK:***

Make a simple animation of an object shot from a catapult. Object is moving through a medium. The problem must be solved in MAPLE.

***NARROWING OF THE PROBLEM:***

- 2D problem
- consider atmospheric density to be constant
- for calculations use Newton's term of the aerodynamics resistance
- animation: simple point following a trajectory

***MY PROGRESS:***

**Fa:=-1/2 * Cd * S * rho * V^2;** //Newton's term of the aerodynamics resistance - absolute value of the force

**Fax:=Fa * cos(alpha); Fay:=Fa * sin(alpha)**; //Components of the vector of the aerodynamics force

**Fax:=subs(cos(alpha)=Vx/V,Fax); Fay:=subs(sin(alpha)=Vy/V,Fay);** //Substitution of the goniometric functions

**Vx:=diff(x(t),t); Vy:=diff(y(t),t); V:=sqrt(Vx^2+Vy^2);** // V = [Vx(t), Vy(t)]=[d * x(t)/dt, d * y(t)/dt]

**Ax:=diff(x(t),t,t)=Fax/m; Ay:=diff(y(t),t,t)=Fay/m-g;** //Aerodynamics deceleration in x and y direction.

**g:=9.81; v:=500.0; Cd:=1.05; d:=1; L:=1; Rho:=2500; S:=evalf(Pi * (d/2)^2); m:=S * L * Rho; rho:=1.22;** // **g** = gravitational acceleration, **v** = projectile initial velocity, **Cd** = coefficient of the projectile's aerodynamic resistance, **d** = projectile's diameter, **Rho** = projectile's mass density, **S** = projectile's cross section, **m** = mass of the projectile, **rho** = density of the atmosphere

**Ini:=x(0)=0,y(0)=0,D(x)(0)=v * cos(alpha),D(y)(0)=v * sin(alpha); alpha:=40;** //Initial conditions. alpha = elevation angle

---

I guess, here should come some nice procedure. The procedure should probably contain some sort of cycle that would solve the ODE and kick out colums of Xs and Ys, that would be used for plotting of the trajectory.

for the animation itself I have even less of an idea.

---

So if anyone have any ideas of how should I proceed, please, share them. More explicit the better.

Thanks V.

Comment: [dsolve](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=dsolve%2fnumeric)?

Comment: NS := dsolve({Ax, Ay, Ini}, {x(t), y(t)}, numeric); dt := 1; while abs(dt) > 0.1e-5 do dt := subs(NS(tau), -y(t)/(diff(y(t), t))); tau := tau+dt end do; R := subs(NS(tau), x(t))

Comment: Where tau-time; R-range; alpha is in radians and not part of Ini. Anyway, it seems to work. Kirill, thanks for your advice regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Maple has its own function for solving ODEs: [dsolve](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=dsolve), which can also solve ODEs numerically ([dsolve/numeric](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=dsolve%2fnumeric)).